# fql query not working for insights

Tags: facebook-insights

I have tried following queries to get my facebook fan page insights data

SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=2439131959 AND metric='application_active_users' AND end_time=end_time_date('2011-06-26') AND period=period('month')

as well as

SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id=111605505520003 AND metric='page_fan_adds' AND end_time=1334905200 AND period=86400

But both are not working. any help will be appreciated . thnks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your access token has the `read_insights` permission. Otherwise querying the insights won't return any data.

Comment: Thanks cpilko for your valueable response. But it returns
 {
  "data": [
  ]
}

I have a question what we need to enter in object_id ?

Comment: It should be your `page_id` or `app_id`. You can verify these through the [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) if you're not sure.

Comment: I am using this to get data https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=<my access token> but it lists pages names as well as applications of user. how can i only get pages name that user admins? thanks

Comment: It's easier to do in [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20page_id%2C%20name%2C%20description%2C%20page_url%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20IN%20(SELECT%20page_id%20from%20page_admin%20WHERE%20uid%3Dme()%20AND%20type%20!%3D%20%22APPLICATION%22)): `SELECT page_id, name, description, page_url FROM page WHERE page_id IN (SELECT page_id from page_admin WHERE uid=me() AND type != "APPLICATION")`